# Odd varible type issue

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

When I do:

```
[int64]$VHDSize = ($vm | Get-VMHardDiskDrive | Get-VHD ).Size
```

returns the error

```
Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.Int64".
```

I know it's because the value I am returning is a different type to the [INT64] value I am after, but it is just a number and I thought it would just convert. and I can't for the life in me work out how to get around this.

Thanks in advance

Frank

Comment: Try `[int64]$VHDSize = $vm | Get-VMHardDiskDrive | Get-VHD | Select -Expand Size`

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to cast an array as a single value. Instead, cast to an array of integers.

```
[int64[]]$VHDSize = ($vm | Get-VMHardDiskDrive | Get-VHD).Size
```